# How can I add a statusnet account in gwibber?

Tags: gwibber, online-accounts

I'd like to add my [StatusNet](http://status.net/) account (not [identi.ca](http://identi.ca/)) to Gwibber, which seems to have this ability, judging by the [gwibber-service-statusnet [image: Install gwibber-service-statusnet]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gwibber-service-statusnet) package.

The trouble is that when you go to add an account, instead of the old Gwibber account screen, it now takes me to the central Online Accounts settings menu, which makes no mention of StatusNet!

Is this still possible?

Comment: I see this on 12.10 as well, it's not just 13.04.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu(version number or name) are you using?

Comment: @Alvar, It has not been tagged with 12.10. Its easier for users to tell their ubuntu version number rather than Gwibber version number, so only asked it. :)